# Nothing is happening after i sign in to a google account

Tags: javascript, java, html, google-oauth

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Sign-In</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="MY_client_id_that_i_replaced_to_post_here.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

<style>
.g-signin2{
    margin-left:500px;
    margin-top:200px;
}
.data{
    display:none
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn()"></div>
<div class="data">
<p>Profile Details</p>
<img id="pic" class="img-circle" width="100" height="100"/>
<p>Email Addres</p>
<p id="email" class="alert alert-danger"></p>
<button onclick="SignOut()" class="btn btn-danger">SignOut</button>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    $(".g-signin2").css("display", "none");
    $(".data").css("display", "block");
    $("#pic").attr("src", profile.getImageUrl());
    $("#email").text(profile.getEmail());
}
function SignOut() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.SignOut().then(function () {
        alert("You have been successfully signed out");
        $(".g-signin2").css("display", "block");
        $(".data").css("display", "none");
    });
}
```

Respectively are the html and javascript files. Google sign in button is working but it's not doing anything after i sign in. It's supposed to display of the google sign in button to none and show me the data attributes of the logged in user.
Also I'm having few errors:

Function onSignIn and SignOut are defined bot not in use

'strict use' missing before var profile and before var auth2

$ used but not defined

gapi used but not defined

alert used but not defined

Comment: [Check out the Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/java).

Comment: Hey Rafa, I've edited the question to what I have reached so far, would you mind giving it another look please?

Comment: Edit : I've detected the problem and it being that data-onsuccess is not doing anything... I've checked the 3rd party cookies and it is not being blocked by chrome

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who stumbles upon this while trying to implement google sign in into your web apps. If you're facing this issue when the onSignIn is not being invoked:

Clear cache from your browser. For some reason that worked.

Also make sure that you whitelist your origin on client_id **and add the port if it's not 80**

Basically this fixed it because i managed to pinpoint the error to data-onsuccess.